# How to Initialize JMS Serializer in Symfony3?

Tags: php, jmsserializerbundle, symfony, jms-serializer

I am trying to use the [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) for Symfony3 (which just came out).

These are the namespaces I've loaded in my `TestController.php`

`use JMS\Serializer\Serializer;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;`

I've tried `$data = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($data, 'json');` where `$data` is just a simple object, but get the following error:

`Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "AppBundle\Controller\TestController"`

I've also tried a usage example from the site `$serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');`, but get `Notice: Undefined variable: container`

I am still new to Symfony3 and its bundles, and can't seem to find any documention on JMS Serializer for symfony 3

I can initialize it like this `$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();` which allows me to call the `serialize` method, but I would like to know the correct "symfony way" of doing it.

If anyone can shed some knowledge, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use container in your controller, your controller must extend Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller or at least 
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware,

anyway if you want to start developing in Symfony I suggest you to start reading error messages, in this specific case your errors are very clear.